# ToTensor() can not convert an image to tensor, and meet a TypeError?

Tags: pytorch

I meet a torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(img). When I directly input an image(128*128), it's wrong. But when I rename the function ttensor = transforms.ToTensor(), it works!
Just like this:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torchvision import transforms

c = np.random.randn(128,128)
d = transforms.ToTensor([c])
# wrong,
# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
ttensor = transforms.ToTensor()
e = ttensor(c)
# right
```

I don't know how to explain this. I want to know why a new variable can be in effect.

```
ttensor = transforms.ToTensor()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that [`transforms.ToTensor`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.ToTensor.html#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor) is a **class**, so calling it will return an instance of that transformation, it expects the transformation parameters (if any) and initializes it. You can call the instance with a tensor and that will perform the operation. The correct way to use it is:

```
transform = transforms.ToTensor()
e = transform(c)
```

In case you only want to call the transformation straight away, you can use its functional form: [`transforms.functional.to_tensor`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor.html):

```
e = transforms.functional.to_tensor(c)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I know it is a class not a function.